# Force user to use jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 app, I am using the jquery.ui.datepicker.css to implement the datepicker for an input field as follows:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtDate", new { @class = "date", @title = "(mm/dd/yyyy)"})
```

When user clicks the textbox, the datepicker (calendar) popups where user can select a date. Some users just prefer to start typing the date instead. How can I force user to use the datepicker instead. I added the attribute @readonly = "readonly" into the textbox but the browsers then make the color of the textbox grayed out making user think that he/she cannot do anything there.

Please help.

Comment: You could make the field a hidden field, and use a span to display what the user chose. Keep in mind though that I could use the console or fiddler to change the value to whatever I wanted despite any restrictions you put on the UI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should add 
    **style="background:white;"** 
to make looks like it is writable

```
<input type="text" id="txtDate" class="date" readonly="readonly" style="background:white;"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution. I had tried background-color="white" but that did not work. One more attribute I ended up adding is border-style:none because the readonly attribute also makes the solid black borders around the textbox. So I added style="background:white;border-style:none;"